# Co-occurrence calculation

Tags: oracle11g, collaborative-filtering

i have a table with two columns:

> ```
> (doc_id, keyword_id)
> ```

I want to calculate the Co-occurrence of two keywords on the documents in the data base. I'm using an Oracle 11g database. The calculation takes one year.
I have 7000 documents, and 5000 keywords.

```
Co-occurrence (keyword1, keyword2)=025.
```

Comment: What is the question?  You should also provide more code to show what you've done so far (not the whole Bible, just a few chapters)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you also have some `count` column? You're going to join the table with itself on `doc_id`, then group by both instances of `keyword_id` (from each reference to the same table in the join), and select both `keyword_id` and the `sum` of the product of the counts.